# Sorting Array of structs with bubblesort based on struct parameter not working

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I have an array of structs and I want to sort it based on element of struct. I am doing bubble sort. When I print out the array it stays the same.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < CountExistingLines() - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < CountExistingLines() - i -1; j++)
    {
        if (structure[j].amount < structure[j+1].amount)
            {
                swap(structure[j], structure[j+1]);
            }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < CountExistingLines(); i++)
{
    cout << "ID: " << structure[i].ID << endl;
    cout << "Typ: " << structure[i].type << endl;
    cout << "Kategorie: " << structure[i].category << endl;
    cout << "Castka: " << structure[i].amount << endl;
    cout << "Datum: " << structure[i].date << endl;
}
```

It prints out unchanged array. I expect the highest amount to be first element of array and the lowest to be last.

**Output**

Pro zapis: 1, pro ukonceni: 2: 2
Konec programu.

ID: 1
Typ: prijem
Kategorie: jine
Castka: 2000
Datum: 21.08.2017

ID: 2
Typ: prijem
Kategorie: vyplata
Castka: 2000
Datum: 21.05.2017

ID: 3
Typ: vydaj
Kategorie: strava
Castka: 3000
Datum: 23.08.2017

ID: 4
Typ: prijem
Kategorie: vyplata
Castka: 25000
Datum: 13.08.2017

ID: 5
Typ: vydaj
Kategorie: bydleni
Castka: 12000
Datum: 21.08.2017

ID: 6
Typ: vydaj
Kategorie: strava
Castka: 3000
Datum: 23.08.2017

ID: 7
Typ: prijem
Kategorie: vyplata
Castka: 25000
Datum: 13.08.2017

ID: 8
Typ: vydaj
Kategorie: bydleni
Castka: 12000
Datum: 21.08.2017

ID: 9
Typ: vydaj
Kategorie: strava
Castka: 3000
Datum: 23.08.2017

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.069 s
Press any key to continue.

**I want it to be like this**

ID: 4 Typ: prijem Kategorie: vyplata Castka: 25000 Datum: 13.08.2017

ID: 7 Typ: prijem Kategorie: vyplata Castka: 25000 Datum: 13.08.2017

ID: 8 Typ: vydaj Kategorie: bydleni Castka: 12000 Datum: 21.08.2017

ID: 5 Typ: vydaj Kategorie: bydleni Castka: 12000 Datum: 21.08.2017

ID: 3 Typ: vydaj Kategorie: strava Castka: 3000 Datum: 23.08.2017

ID: 6 Typ: vydaj Kategorie: strava Castka: 3000 Datum: 23.08.2017

ID: 9 Typ: vydaj Kategorie: strava Castka: 3000 Datum: 23.08.2017

ID: 1 Typ: prijem Kategorie: jine Castka: 2000 Datum: 21.08.2017

ID: 2 Typ: prijem Kategorie: vyplata Castka: 2000 Datum: 21.05.2017

Comment: what does swap method do. add swap code also.

Comment: it is method from library, not my function

Comment: what language is this you are using?

Comment: Czech, it is homework, does it matter?

Comment: @MarekSpányik I believe he meant programming language, @SuryaSubenthiran I believe `swap` is `template<typename T> void std::swap(T&,T&)` from C++ standard library

Comment: @MarekSpányik The code you written is fine. the problem should be in CountExistingLines function. so add the logic of CountExistingLines also.

Comment: Best guess: `structure` is a parameter to the function of the form `std::vector<SomeType> structure`, and should instead be `std::vector<SomeType> & structure`, you are sorting a copy, the original is unchanged